# I'm sorry, I messed up. Twice

Tags: discussion

My apologies.

---

I want this place to make it, to be *the* place for high quality elementary OS question and answers, and I'm trying to make it that way for our public launch. This could be a gem of the internet and I want to watch it grow.

---

The editing - I made a big mistake. I misunderstood the terminology used, and that changed the whole question.

Thank you - for calling me out on meta. Seriously. I made the mistake and I'm grateful I realised I'd made it.

I am sorry I made the mistake - and I've done the best I can to fix it. I did my best to explain this mistake in an answer which I hope explains my mistake.

---

And the request. Yep, I was asking for invisible code. This is from my background - I am mainly active on Ask Ubuntu, which has a very different community to here. On Ask Ubuntu you don't (often) find the people developing the next release - I guess that this is the big difference. Here, we're lucky enough to have not one but two devs (that I know of) active. Thanks to them (any any others I don't know about)!

So, yes. I was asking a dev for evidence that the team wasn't considering something. Sorry.

Comment: Don't be hard on yourself. We're in beta and we're humans. Mistakes will happen or my name is not RolandiXor (it isn't).

Comment: I know I was just frustrated when I looked back at it. Thanks though :)

Comment: just for your information there are around 10 or more devs on here (almost every active dev) :)